# What is cylindrical Brownian Motion / Wiener Process

Tags: hilbert-spaces, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

I have been given some reading on the Krylov-Bogoliubov Method for constructing invariant measures.

An SDE in  Hilbert space H is introduced as

$$d(X)=b(X)dt + \sigma(X)dW  $$

Where W is the cylindrical Wiener Process on the Hilbert space. I have only seen Brownian Motions in $R$ and am struggling to understand the big picture/general intuition behind B.M on general spaces and what a cylindrical Wiener Process is. Any suggested reading, or helpful insights?

Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.2261) or [this](http://www.hairer.org/notes/SPDEs.pdf) may help.